# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Produccion

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, casting

I have several clases in a package called Produccion. I want to call to the function in the class "Puesto" from the class "Principal".
In the class principal I have this:

```
private void verAGVs() {
    ((Puesto) puestos).testear();

}
public void gestionarAGVs() {
    crearPuestos();
    crearAGVs();
    verAGVs();
    iniciar();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Principal programa = new Principal();
    programa.gestionarAGVs();

}
```

The problem is that i have an error in the function verAGVs:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Produccion.Puesto

The function in the class Puesto is the next one:

```
public void testear() {
    AGV anterior= null;
    for (AGV agv: lista) {
        soporte.firePropertyChange("AGV", anterior, agv);
        anterior = agv;
        agv.testear();
        
    }
}
```

Please help me;

Comment: It seems that `puestos` is not a `Puesto` object, but a List of `Puesto` objects .

Comment: Where is `puestos` declared? Could you show that line too?

Comment: You should include a more complete example so we can see where ArrayList comes into play.